# Intersection of two algebras on different spaces not an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Reviewing my lecture notes, I have trouble understanding why the intersection of the following two algebras behaves as it does:

$$ \mathcal{A} = \left\{A \subseteq \mathbb{N}: |A| < \infty \text{ or } |A^c| < \infty  \right\}$$

$$ \mathcal{B} = \left\{B \subseteq \mathbb{Z}: |B| < \infty \text{ or } |B^c| < \infty  \right\},$$

where $A^c$ and $B^c$ denote the complements of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

I was told that the intersection of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is equal to $\left\{A \subseteq \mathbb{N}: |A| < \infty \right\}$.

Why isn't $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B}$ equal to $\mathcal{A}$ itself? Why isn't it an algebra?

Thanks for enlightening me! Much obliged for any input!

Comment: What does the notation $B^c$ mean?

Comment: Complement to $B$

Comment: I'm just confused about what you mean by complement of a number. Assuming you mean the complement of the singleton set (i.e. $\mathbb Z - \{A\}$) there are no numbers whose complement is finite. So you surely mean something else? If it was $A\subset \mathbb Z$ it would make sense.

Comment: yes, you're correct

Comment: I mistyped, I'm sorry

Comment: No worries, it makes sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that, when taking complements, the "universal" set matters. In the first set, $A^c$ means $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$; whereas in the second, $B^c$ means $\mathbb{Z}\setminus B$.

> It is indeed true that $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}=\{A\subseteq\mathbb{N}: |A|<\infty\}$.

*Proof:*
Suppose $A\in \mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}$. Then $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, so $\mathbb{Z}\setminus A$ is infinite. Since $A\in\mathcal{B}$, we conclude that $A$ is finite.
The converse is easy. $\square$

For an explicit example why $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}\not\supseteq\mathcal{A}$, consider the set $A:=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Wow, this was a very good proof! I enjoyed understanding it.

Comment: Since I had to green-tick a helper, I programmed a random draw that favoured you, good sir.

Comment: May I know the purpose/reason of the "white medium square" character after the "*The converse is easy.*"?

Comment: @AndrewT. : ​ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.#Typographical_forms_used_symbolically ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Ah, I see. I know the expression Q.E.D., but apparently, I rarely see it in symbolic form. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Think about a cofinite set in $\mathbb N$. It contains all natural numbers except finitely many.

But if you consider it as a subset of $\mathbb Z$, there are infinitely many negative numbers that it doesn't contain, so its complement is not finite. Thus the cofinite sets in $\mathbb N$ are not cofinite in $\mathbb Z$.

(But the finite sets in $\mathbb N$ are automatically finite sets in $\mathbb Z$!)

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you a lot, @neptun. The concept of cofiniteness was alien to me!

Comment: Sorry, "cofinite set" just means "set whose complement is finite"!

Comment: No worries, I'm here to learn!